# Redirect to a subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I'm following a tutorial and I have a redirect problem.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04.

The project file is located in the `/var/www/html` directory and is named `tuto`

My directory tuto has the following directories: `/controller`, `/view`, `/model`, `/core` and `webroot` and as file it has `index.php` and `.htaccess`

The webroot directory has the following directories: `/css`, `/img`, `/js` and as `index.php` file

I would like that, when this url: `//localhost/tuto/css/style.css` is entered, that the `.htaccess` file will look it up in the `webroot/css/style.css`

How do I code this?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply redirect that specific file in the htaccess file.
i assume you have in it few redirections so put it before all of them:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^css/style.css webroot/css/style.css [QSA,NC]
```

and in your html code just call it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but I would like something more general that works with all urls.
Here is what the tutorial proposes and which does not work:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but I would like something more general that works with all urls.
Here is what the tutorial proposes to me in the .htaccess file of the root and which does not work:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (. *) Webroot / $ 1 [L]

And in the .htaccess file of the webroot:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% [REQUEST_FILENAME]%! -d
RewriteCond% [REQUEST_FILENAME]%! -f
RewriteRule (. *) Webroot / $ 1 [L]

I tried, but I still have a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You could do what they've suggested, it might make conflicts with your other htaccess rewrite rules. i would just go simple and do

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^css webroot/css [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^js webroot/js [QSA,NC]
```

then every link to the css/js folders will actually call webroot folder

Comment: @MathurinAbossoloEvina

Comment: Solved your problem?